# кэширование ajax запроса

Tags: ajax, кэширование

Нужно сделать кэширование.
Логика такая, нажатие на ссылку(кэширую данные), затем нажатие на кнопку(перехожу к другому контенту), и нажатие назад кнопки браузера[вот здесь и нужно подставить кэш] чтобы не делать лищний запрос в базу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вам попробовать небольшой jQuery-плагин [Jalc](https://github.com/SaneMethod/jquery-ajax-localstorage-cache), который кэширует AJAX-запросы, используя localStorage. И велосипед изобретать не надо.

```
$.ajax({
    localCache: true,
    cacheTTL: 2,
    cacheKey: 'list_of_phones',
    isCacheValid: function () { return true; },

    url: '/phones',

    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // Закэшированный запрос будет в переменной data.
        // Если в кэше нет данных или если они устарели,
        // то будет сделан AJAX-запрос, а его результат (если он
        // был успешным) также будет храниться в переменной data.
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {/* ... */},
});
```

Comment: спасибо, да попадался он мне. есть ещё нюанс нужно отобразить данные с разных ajax запросов(то есть эти 3 запроса предоставляют единую страницу.)

Comment: @Zimzibar, вы можете каждому AJAX-запросу указывать различный ключ, под которым он будет храниться в localStorage. Смотрите параметр `cacheKey`.

Comment: да я это делал, а как допустим распечатать то что находится в localStorage?
Делаю так: $('body').(localStorage.getItem(main_page) ) да знаю в Jalc там просто метод .get, и не работает.

И ещё минус Jalca в том что у меня JSON приходит в виде for_json[0] и я его parse в ajax parseJSON[for_json[0]] Что немного не подходит для Jalc и там просто null

Comment: @Zimzibar, делайте обычный AJAX-запрос. Если данные закэшированы, то запрос делаться не будет, а автоматически данные возьмутся из localStorage. Добавил пример в свой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за поддержку, вот посмотрите как на данный момент у меня. 1) ajax запрос берёт данные из главной страницы, далее 2 и 3 ajax запросы берут данные и вставляют в 'body' главной страницы . И для чего я делаю кэш так это -> если нажимают на кнопку а она переносит на другую страницу совсем и затем нажимают назад(то есть возвращаются на главную) тут я и хочу  использовать кэш и попросту взять и распечатать из localstorage снова в body

Comment: @Zimzibar, на самом деле, я не очень понимаю, чего вы хотите добиться. Но чтобы кэширование заработало, просто добавьте новые параметры из данного плагина к уже существующим AJAX-запросам. Вам никаких существенных изменений в коде вносить не нужно - надо просто добавить 4 новых параметра к AJAX-запросам, которые хотите кэшировать.

Comment: Говорю же что выше его я использовал, но там проблема в том что нужно данные в правильном формате представить(иначе просто возвращает fail[object, Object]).
Ещё такой вопрос, например после ознакомления понял что memcached использовать нужно в больших проектах и в закрытых CDN в общем сетях, а для таких малых проектов только средства подобия Jalc остаётся использовать?) Спасибо.

Comment: @Zimzibar, memcached - это кэширование данных на стороне бэкэнда в оперативной памяти сервера. Используйте где хотите, лишь бы количество памяти позволяло. Его используют потому, что оперативная память быстрее чтения диска и БД. А вы спрашиваете про кэширование на стороне клиента - это разные вещи и, соответственно, две совершенно разные и огромные темы для обсуждения. Если вкратце про фронтэнд, то в любом проекте выставляйте правильные заголовки на кэширование ассетов, используйте параметр `cache: true` в jQuery AJAX и, по возможности, применяйте Jalc - всё это очень сильно снизит нагрузку.